# Xpath is not working correctly

Tags: c#

I'm using htmlagilitypack to scrape info from websites. It was working fine until one of the websites I'm using has xpaths that aren't working. I'm fairly new to coding so I'm not really sure how to go about this. I've tried googling and it nothing I found worked. here is the code.

```
 string searchUsernameUrl = "https://www.r6db.com/search/" + txtUsername.Text;

        HtmlWeb searchWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument searchDoc = searchWeb.Load(searchUsernameUrl);

 try
        {
            txtUplayID.Text = searchDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='mount']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span")[0].InnerText;
        }
 catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to provide aliases.", "Error");
        }
```

Right now I'm trying to get the ID on the page beneath the first result, but no matter what I try I always get an error.

Comment: What error? You should catch the exception (***catch (Exception ex)***) and see what is the actual errormessage.

Comment: Try what @Esko said, but at a guess I'd say your Xpath query isn't matching, but you're assuming that it is by trying to access the results (via the [0].InnerText). In that case you really need to work out what you'd like to do when the Xpath doesn't match.

Comment: The specific error that occurs is NullReferenceException was unhandled. @Esko

Comment: Then it's pretty obvious that since you are making an assumption that something will be found with the xpath-query (the [0]-index) you are wrong and you get a NullReferenceException when trying to read InnerText from null.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to Xpaths and c#. Can you explain what I would have to do to fix it? I just used chrome to find the xpath and pasted it into the code.

Comment: Since your XPath query isn't giving the result you expect, you need to look at the retrieved HTML yourself and construct a correct query to get what you want. If you want help with constructing that query, then you need to provide the source HTML and tell us which portion you're trying to select. (It may be better to do so in another question.)

Comment: because the url is wrong, the website get data from "https://r6db.com/api/v2/players?name=" + txtUsername.Text

Comment: as far as I know, html is not valid xml, so parsing it as if it was will not work in general (it might in specific cases). my point is that relying on xpath for html will bite you sooner or later

Answer (score 0):

Since the Page is a browser-rendered one you have to execute the javscript too. also you might hit timing issues.
I'd suggest using the api directly which returns JSON:
url: `https://r6db.com/api/v2/players?name=[NAME]&exact=[1 or 0]`.
just be sure to set a x-app-id header or you won't get any response.

source: i made that frontend